# Programmatically stop execution of python script after running condition statement

Tags: python, quit

How do you programmatically stop a python script after a condition sentence has run through. In the pseudo script below:

```
for row in rows:

    if row.FIRSTDATE == row.SECONDDATE:
        pass
    else:
        print "FIRSTDATE does not match SECONDDATE " + row.UNIQUEID

## If I set my quit sequence at the this tab level, it quits after the first
## unmatched record is found. I don't want that, I want it to quit after all the
## unmatched records have been found, if any. if all records match, I want the
## script to continue and not quit

        sys.quit("Ending Script")
```

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 2):

```
quit_flag = False
for row in rows:

    if row.FIRSTDATE == row.SECONDDATE:
        pass
    else:
        print "FIRSTDATE does not match SECONDDATE " + row.UNIQUEID
        quit_flag = True

if quit_flag:
    print "Ending Script"
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i understand correctly

```
doQuit = 0
for row in rows:
    if row.FIRSTDATE != row.SECONDDATE:
        print "FIRSTDATE does not match SECONDDATE " + row.UNIQUEID
        doQuit = 1
if doQuit: sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. This does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
def DifferentDates(row):
    if row.FIRSTDATE != row.SECONDDATE:
        print "FIRSTDATE does not match SECONDDATE " + row.UNIQUEID
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Fill a list with Trues and Falses, using the check above
checked_rows = map(DifferentDates, rows)

# If any one row is different, sys exit
if any(checked_rows):
    sys.exit()
```

Documentation for [any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: Thanks Campos. I tried using this and it's exiting for me. I was playing around with your suggestion to add print lines to the function. I placed them at the same tab level as 'return' but that doesn't seem to print for me. How would I set a print line to return any unmatched records? Thanks!

Comment: @mike-macrae Edited to add prints; That 'else' is not necessary, but it's there for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
mis_match = []

for row in rows:
    if row.FIRSTDATE != row.SECONDDATE:
        mis_match.append(row.UNIQUEID)

if mis_match:
  print "The following rows didn't match" + '\n'.join(mis_match)
  sys.exit()
```